# How to encode call data to a contract

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

Reading through the ink source code ([here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/core/src/env2/call/utils.rs#L83)), my understanding is that a contract call is the selector concatenated with any arguments to the function.

From a Substrate runtime module test, I use the CallData builder which does as described

```rust
let mut call = CallData::new( Selector::from_str("foo") );
call.push_arg(&0);
```

And then make the call through the contracts frame module

```rust
let res = <contracts::Module<Test>>::bare_call(      
    ALICE,                                                      
    contract_addr,                                                       
    0,                                                          
    100_000,                                                                                    
    //codec::Encode::encode(&call.to_bytes().to_vec()));        
    call.to_bytes().to_vec());
```

To a contract function signature of

```
fn foo(&self, x: AccountId)
```

---

This returns a successful execution (`Ok(())`) but does not invoke the contract function.

It's worth saying that the test is using `type AccountId = u64` and ink uses a `struct AccountId([u8;32])`, but I've tried passing as 32 bytes and it hasn't made a difference.

I've verified that the surrounding test code should work by calling a wasm program written in wat [here](https://github.com/jaybutera/nft-registry/blob/master/runtime/src/nftregistry/tests.rs#L265), which is able to call the exported "call" without passing any parameters.

The complete repositories are also on github for the [module](https://github.com/jaybutera/nft-registry) and the [contract](https://github.com/jaybutera/nftregistry-testcontract).

Comment: This sounds like the contract doesn't actually gets called. If it actually was called and the input data is incorrect then you should see a trap, coming from ink!

Comment: How could it not be called though? Only the contract address could be wrong and that is generated straight from the contracts module https://github.com/jaybutera/nft-registry/blob/master/runtime/src/nftregistry/tests.rs#L394